# Taking too much time to load select multiple in angular

Tags: angular

I am creating a multiple selection select box to select multiple users, these are the lines to create the multiple selection

```
<select formControlName="userIds" id="userIds" multiple>
        <option *ngFor="let opt of data" [value]="opt.id" class = "form-control">{{opt.userId}}</option>
      </select>
```

But it's taking too much time to load the contents inside the select box. If we are removing the "multiple" option from the select box it will load fastly. How can we fix this issue?

Comment: Hello! There are some variables that needs to be considered. The values of 'data', is static or dynamically loaded through an API call?

Comment: Yes, the value of data is dynamically loaded through the api call and it's getting fastly.

Comment: I changed it to the check box and after that, there is no delay in loading the dynamic data. Thanks for the help.